# Daily Cron Job Example

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want to run a command daily on an Ubuntu Linux box @ 9:15PM. Is this the correct entry for my crontab?

```
15 23 * * * <<command>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is, the hours not

```
minute hour dayofmonth month dayofweek     command
```

Your command will run every day at 23:15 (11:15pm)

9pm is 21 (in 24h writing 12 + 9 = 21)

```
15 21 * * *  command
```